# Refactor repetitive EntityFramework's Fluent API statements

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics, .net-core

I currently have the following (excerpt) code to properly map many-to-many relationships in EF Core:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<LifeCourseNameTranslation>()
            .HasKey(pc => new { pc.TranslationId, pc.LifeCourseId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<LifeCourseNameTranslation>()
            .HasOne(pc => pc.LifeCourse)
            .WithMany(p => p.LifeCourseNameTranslations)
            .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.LifeCourseId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LifeCourseNameTranslation>()
            .HasOne(pc => pc.Translation)
            .WithMany(c => c.LifeCourseNameTranslations)
            .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.TranslationId);


        modelBuilder.Entity<StrataNameTranslation>()
            .HasKey(pc => new { pc.TranslationId, pc.StrataId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<StrataNameTranslation>()
            .HasOne(pc => pc.Strata)
            .WithMany(p => p.StrataNameTranslations)
            .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.StrataId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<StrataNameTranslation>()
            .HasOne(pc => pc.Translation)
            .WithMany(c => c.StrataNameTranslations)
            .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.TranslationId);


        modelBuilder.Entity<PointLabelTranslation>()
            .HasKey(pc => new { pc.TranslationId, pc.PointId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PointLabelTranslation>()
            .HasOne(pc => pc.Point)
            .WithMany(p => p.PointLabelTranslations)
            .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.PointId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PointLabelTranslation>()
            .HasOne(pc => pc.Translation)
            .WithMany(c => c.PointLabelTranslations)
            .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.TranslationId);
```

And this goes on for a while longer. These seem very repetitive and look like something which could be refactored into a series of method calls looking something like

```
BindJoinTable(ModelBuilder, Table1, Table2, JoinTable)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: They're all different, so any refactoring won't make it any smaller or easier to read.

Comment: There are essentially only 2 differences, the name of the generics and the name of the IDs. The name of the ID can be identified through annotations I'm guessing. Currently I am copy-pasting a dozen lines of code for every relationship I need and occasionally make mistakes which are very painful to debug.

Comment: Why don't you specify the relations using attributes on the classes themselves?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev those calls aren't repetitive, they create different *relations*. Just because some property *names* are the same doesn't mean the types or properties are. *If* the classes implemented a common interface with common properties, you could create a generic method that accepted a type with a constraint on that interface and have it define the relation. Those calls though use different properties each time.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev to put it another way, those are pretty significant differences. I don't see even one relation or key that uses the same property names. If you created eg a method that used reflection maybe, just like the Fluent API does, I don't think you would save many keystrokes

Comment: For simple relationships you can leverage attributes on the entities. My preference is to use configuration classes that extend EntityTypeConfiguration to contain my mappings then have the modelBuilder load them from the assembly. `modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly)` (assuming the entity configs are in the same assembly as the DbContext)  Keeps them nice and organized in separate classes tucked away in a folder under the entities.